# How to extract firebase daily user engagement from BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, filter, google-bigquery, metrics

I have a firebase connection with BigQuery and i want to extract the daily user engagement information that is present on the analytics dashboard.
[Firebase Analytics Dashboard Daily User Engagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Hvp.png)

I´ve already tried to find the numbers using EVENT_NAME filter as 'user_engagement', 'screen_view' and EVENT_PARAMS_KEY as 'engagement_time_msec', 'engaged_session_event'.
With the filter mentioned previously i couldn´t even get near from the firebase values.
Somebody knows how to reach them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485), user engagement data collection is triggered periodically by Firebase SDK, while the app is running in the foreground. Saying this, for `user_engagement` we might be looking over the events, filtering for the entry where `event_params.key = "engagement_time_msec"` and fetching the `event_params.value.int_value` from there.

```
SELECT event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM `firebase*.events_*` 
  WHERE event_name = "user_engagement"
```